# Where is the database connection information in an ADP file?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, adp

A user entered a ticket for an OLD Access database and form project that they use daily.  They are saying that the database cannot be found when they use it.  I haven't used MS Access to design a database or interface since college so I have no idea where to find the database it's trying access.

I want to try and locate the DB to see if 1) it exists and 2) is not corrupt

The main interface is done through a *.adp file.  Where is the connection string information stored in the file?

Ive opened it in MS Access 2007.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With an ADP, SQL Server is used for all data storage.

In the Immediate window (go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>), inspect the `ConnectionString` and `Provider` properties:

```vba
? CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString
? CurrentProject.Connection.Provider
```

Comment: You may want to consider converting that Access application from ADP to a standard MDB or ACCDB format with ODBC links to the SQL Server data source because support for ADP is going away in new Access versions.  Greetings from Littleton.

Comment: Heh, Littleton is where I grew up!  I tried to inspect the CurrentProject.Connection and got [this error](http://i.imgur.com/TGrKr.png) I did copy the entire folder to my desktop to prevent me messing anything up on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I quit using ADP some years back.  See whether the updated answer gets you the information you need.

Comment: Turns our someone turned off the server the DB was on.  Got to love having servers throughout the country setup in broom closets.